# Search value within array

Tags: c++

My code, I'm trying to search through the entire array to find a value.
I'm adding detail. Lots of detail. I am a beginner.

This is for my Computer Science course at UTD.

```
// 2DimensionalArrayExp1  
// This program is part of Project 2
// As part of your assignment on this program, you will turn the process through the array
// into a function and add a third dimension

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>  // Needed for rand and srand
#include <ctime>    // Needed for the time function
#include <math.h> // sqrt function
using namespace std;

void processThrough(int array[10][10][10]);
void searchArray(int array[10][10][10]);

int main()
{
    // estabish array and set all values to 0
    int myArray[10][10][10] = { 0 };
    int myArray2[10][10][10] = { 0 };

    // establish x and y position markers
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int z = 0;

    // establish input for x and y from the user
    int xInput = 0;
    int yInput = 0;
    int zInput = 0;
    int x2Input = 0;
    int y2Input = 0;
    int z2Input = 0;

    // variable for value entered
    int inputValue = 0;
    int inputValue2 = 0;

    double distance = 0;

    // Get the user's value and coordinate
    cout << "\nPlease enter the x coordinate ";
    cin >> xInput;
    cout << "\nPlease enter the y coordinate ";
    cin >> yInput;
    cout << "\nPlease enter the z coordinate ";
    cin >> zInput;
    cout << "\nPlease enter the value to place in " << xInput << "," << yInput << ", " << zInput << " ";
    cin >> inputValue;
    cout << "\nPlease enter the x coordinate ";
    cin >> x2Input;
    cout << "\nPlease enter the y coordinate ";
    cin >> y2Input;
    cout << "\nPlease enter the z coordinate ";
    cin >> z2Input;
    cout << "\nPlease enter the value to place in " << x2Input << "," << y2Input << ", " << z2Input << " ";
    cin >> inputValue2;

    // place the value in the coordinate
    myArray[xInput][yInput][zInput] = inputValue;
    cout << "\nYou have successfully placed the value " << inputValue << " in coordinate " << xInput << ", " << yInput << ", " << zInput << " ";

    myArray[x2Input][y2Input][z2Input] = inputValue2;
    cout << "\nYou have successfully placed the value " << inputValue2 << " in coordinate " << x2Input << ", " << y2Input << ", " << z2Input << " ";

    // Process through the array
    processThrough(myArray);

    // indicate end of array processing
    cout << "\nArray Processed" << endl;

    distance = sqrt(((x2Input - xInput) * (x2Input - xInput)) + ((y2Input - yInput) * (y2Input - yInput)) + ((z2Input - zInput) * (z2Input - zInput)));
    cout << "\nThe distance between the two points is: " << distance;

    searchArray(myArray);

    cin.get();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}

void processThrough(int array[10][10][10]) {
    // Process through the array
    for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++)
        {
            for (int z = 0; z < 10; z++) {
                // Display the value of the coordinate
                cout << "\nCoordinate " << x << ", " << y << ", " << z << " " << "value is " << array[x][y][z];
            }
        }
    }
}

void searchArray(int array[10][10][10])
{
    int searchValue, x, y, z;
    cout << "\nEnter value: ";
    cin >> searchValue;
    for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
    {
        if (array[x][y][z] == searchValue)
        {

        }
        for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++)
        {
            for (int z = 0; z < 10; z++) {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe at the end? Please let me know what's wrong!

Comment: Move the if statement into the for loop iterating through z.

Comment: yeah... Should have thought of that. Been working an hour on that now. Thank you Abbath.

Comment: In general, *break the problem into simpler ones.* Try scanning a simple array (`int array[10]`), then once you've mastered that, 2 dimensions (`int[10][10]`), then three.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you are defining twice the variables `x, y, z` in `searchArray` function.
Then you compare for a value in `array[x][y][z]` on indexes which are not defined, because you are not initializing this variables. Correct code should look like this:

```
void searchArray(int array[10][10][10])
{
    int searchValue;
    cout << "\nEnter value: ";
    cin >> searchValue;
    for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++)
        {
            for (int z = 0; z < 10; z++) 
            {
               if (array[x][y][z] == searchValue)
               {
                   //Whatever you want to do
               }
               else
               {
                   cout << "Value not found";
               }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your searchArray function has two big problems.

1. You define `x`, `y` and `z` twice. The variables within the loops that act as indexes shadow the ones you declare at the top of the function.
2. You search for `array[x][y][z]` outside of the deepest part of the loop for some reason.

Try this:

```
std::tuple<int,int,int> searchArray(int array[][][])
{
    int searchValue;
    cout << "\nEnter value: ";
    cin >> searchValue;
    for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++)
        {
            for (int z = 0; z < 10; z++)
            {
                if (array[x][y][z] == searchValue)
                {
                    return std::make_tuple(x, y, z);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return std::make_tuple(-1,-1,-1);   // Or something to indicate no match found
}
```

This will return a `tuple` of `(x,y,z)` for the indexes where it found the match in your array.

Comment: I had a friend telling me to put the if loop within the for loop and misunderstood.